# two UITableViews inside one UIViewController

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have two UITableViews (tableView and tableViewevent) on the same controller. Unfortunately, Xcode is not allowing me to do this. What I want is below:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (UITableView == self.tableVie) {
```

Xcode keeps wanting to change it to the code below, but the problem is that it crashes on the other tableview (tableViewevent). How do I properly do something like this?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableVie == self.tableVie) {
```

Lastly, the tables also do not return any cells (even though nslog shows data there). I'm using this for cellsatrowforindex:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"cell";
    if ([UITableView isEqual:self.tableVie]) {
```

Comment: `if ([UITableView isEqual:self.tableVie]) ` you cannot compare classes to objects. please don't make some code up. give us your code.

Comment: I'm not making it up. That is my code. Was I doing it wrong?

Comment: This code should not even compile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (table == self.tableVie) {
```

to compare the parameter with your instance variable. You might want to consider using a container view controller approach and having separate controllers for each of the tables to keep your code clear and your logic separate.

Comment: shouldn't you be using isEqual instead of ==?

Comment: and for cellatrowatindex: I would use what, because the above just returns blank cells.

Comment: @user1846108: No. `==` is correct, as you want to be sure that on both sides are the same object, not 2 objects, that are equal, but different instances.

Comment: @user3360541  The problem in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` may be the cell identifier `@"cell"`.  Are you using the same identifier for both tables?  You may need to share more of the structure of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` before someone can help you with that.

Comment: I am sharing the identifier...

Comment: Oh, I see the source of confusion now. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it's `if (tv == self.tableVie)`

Comment: That was it the whole time...wow. I feel like an idiot. Thanks so much!